# Can ARIMA be used to forecast future data points that are slightly more than the original observed data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, prediction

my knowledge in statistics is limited and I'm trying to use auto.arima() in R to forecast COVID-19 data. My data set is 97 days and I'm trying to predict a total of 105 days that are divided into phases of 21 days long each. For the first phase, the result found by auto.arima() seems like a good-fit. My questions are:

(1) Will auto.arima() return a valid result when predicting the whole time period of 105 days?
(2) Does auto.arima() take into acount the predicted values of the first 21 days forecasted for phase 1 when trying to predict the next 21 days for phase two?

Comment: Pandemic is non-linear while ARIMA is a linear equation. I'm not sure if the ARIMA is suitable to explain.

Comment: Agree with @kevin012 , I have tried to fit many different ARIMA models to the covid data, they all performed pretty badly thus far, so I am not convinced it is a good fit.